# Filter EventLog based on date

Tags: powershell, get-eventlog

I am trying to pull out some information from the eventlog through PowerShell based on the date today.

So far I have the code below:

```
$today = (Get-Date).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
Get-EventLog Security | where {$_.EventID -eq 4624} | where {$_.TimeGenerated -eq $today}
```

Now I have printed the result of today and can confirm that the outputted date is 04/12/2017, I have also printed the date of the `TimeGenerated` attriubute from the EventID object and that also shows the date in the same format.

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TimeGenerated` property holds a `DateTime` value, not a string, so don't compare it to a date string. Also, you should filter via `Get-EventLog` parameters whenever possible, because that filtering happens at the source. This is particularly relevant when querying remote eventlogs to reduce the amount of data that is transmitted over the network.

```
$today    = (Get-Date).Date
$tomorrow = $today.AddDays(1)

Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceId 4626 -After $today -Before $tomorrow
```